# How to Start an exe from .bat file without tying up the command line

Tags: windows-10, command-line, ssh, batch-file

I am using SSH to command line into another computer and execute .bat scripts.  (Windows 10).  But when I run a batch file that has the following in it

```
start c:\Program Files\qBittorrent\qbittorrent.exe
```

the ssh command line locks up (I am assuming I cannot get control again until the app exits).  So is there a way to run an EXE from command line bat that wont tie up the command prompt and i can execute more commands?  even the ctrl-c didnt work after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because it is showing an error dialog that you can't see (and therefore can't click `Ok`) saying it cannot find your file `C:\Program`. Enclose paths with spaces in quotes.

Also `start` takes the first set of quotes on the line as the window title.

```
start "My Title" "c:\Program Files\qBittorrent\qbittorrent.exe"
```

See `start /?` for a discussion on starting programs normally (by just typing their name) and pre and post Windows 2000 behaviour and also using `start` to start programs in special ways.

Comment: yep, that was it thanks.